# SCRIPT5007: Object expected specifically on IE browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've tried running my script with the following code. This seems to work on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Edge and Brave. I cannot seem to get it to work with Internet Explorer 11 or previous.

Initially, when I created my script, a function in app.js was formatted like so

```
function x() {
  fetch('example.domain')
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then(data => obj = data)
    .then(function(y) {
```

I then discovered that IE does not support the `=>` operator, and refactored this code to

```
function x() {
  fetch('example.domain').then(function (blob) {
    return blob.json();
  }).then(function (data) {
    return obj = data;
  }).then(function (y) {
```

This code now seems to be working fine. The issue has now moved to index.html, where I am trying to display a jQuery datepicker element on the page. The code is formatted like so

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    $(document).on('change', 'select', function () {
      if ($("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate") === null) {
        alert("You have not selected a date.");
      } else {
        x();
      }
    });

    $("#datepicker").show();

    $(function () {
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        onSelect: y,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Which presents the error

> SCRIPT5007: Object expected  index.html, line 8 character 1

Which focuses on the line

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function () {
```

I've investigated the use of jQuery, it has been imported once. I've checked my script against an ES6 validator and it seems to fine. Is there a function jQuery uses that IE browsers do not support, or is my code completely mis-formatted?

Comment: Unless you're using a polyfill you haven't mentioned, `fetch()` in not supported in any version of IE

Comment: Also, in your jQuery logic, you need to move the `show()`  method call inside the document.ready handler, but this won't be causing any console errors.

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).I test your code (about the change function), it seems that everything works well on my side. You could also try to using "  $(function () {
            $("select").change(function () {
                alert("Hello");
            })
        });" to attach the change event.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reading Rory McCrossan's comment, I've implemented [this polyfill](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js). This has allowed me to use the `fetch()` function with IE. No other changes were required to the code.